# How can I show only table rows that contains a radio button value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have for example three radio button like this:

```
 ◉ 0-30 
 ◉ 30-90
 ◉ 90-100
```

and table :

| id | name | età |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | 0-30 |
| 2 | Danny | 30-90 |
| 3 | Elle | 90-100 |

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Carla102030/28r7oxwf/5/

My goal is: when users checked first radio button, in the table he must see only rows with this value and so on. So I want a JS function that works in this way.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried to fix the problem? Please check the "how to ask a question" pages on stackoverflow. Your currently not asking a good question. If there is even a question visible in here...

Comment: @Allar Question edited

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I want a jquery function that filters only rows that contains a radio button value checked. Is not clear, sorry?

Comment: @Carla Yes it's clear what you want, but Stack Overflow is not a coding service, you have to try yourself. When you have tried, show us your effort and we will be happy to assist

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes, I edited my question with code

Comment: @Carla Good now you have added your js attempt. Now please include your html code. Use the  snippet tool `<>` to create a working example of your problem. Also remember to include the trigger that runs your js code

Comment: I understand you tried and know what you want, but as @CarstenLøvboAndersen tries to say (I think), is that your problem is not specific enough. Try out some more and come with 1 specific issue back. Your current one is too broad. For us to be able to help you would have to show you whole html, js etc. and we would have to basicly create the whole logic for you. Thats not how stackoverflow works. If you have a small and easy to understand issue than its a good question.

Comment: I did it @Allart

Comment: You have not added your code.  You added an external site that hosts your code.  Your code, a [mre], needs to be in your ***actual*** question, as text.  Not linked to on an external site.  When JSFiddle implodes, just like several other code hosting sites, this question becomes useless.  That's why it is such a pain point, that's why everyone says to add code to the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery filter function to detect the value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name="filter"]').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (value === "all"){
      $("#myTable tr").show();
    } else {
      $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
    }   
  });
});
```

```css
.table{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table tr, .table th, .table td{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="radioCont">
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="0-30" id="i1" /> <label for="i1"> 0-30</label> <br />
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="30-90" id="i2" /> <label for="i2"> 30-90</label> <br />
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="90-100" id="i3" /> <label for="i3"> 90-100</label> <br />
  <input type="radio" name="filter" value="all" id="i4" checked /> <label for="i4"> All</label> <br />
</div>

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>età</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Sta</td>
        <td>0-30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Danny</td>
        <td>30-90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Elle</td>
        <td>90-100</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: THANKY YOU SO MUCH!